# iptables arp compare and execute

Tags: iptables, scripting, arp, mac-address, sed

EXAMPLE:

**iptables**

:internet - [0:0]
-A internet -m mac --mac-source 48:5D:60:FC:29:B0 -j RETURN

COMMIT

[root@localhost:~ ] $ arp

Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface

10.2.0.1                 ether   48:5D:60:FC:29:B0   C                     br0

i would like to delete the iptable rule (-D internet -m mac --mac-source 48:5D:60:FC:29:B0 -j RETURN) if the mac on ARP list is not present.

Comment: Could you provide some data (source) sample because it is OS/system dependant. Some few f/e/grep should solve the problem (eventually a sed)

Comment: EXAMPLE:

**iptables**
:internet - [0:0]
-A internet -m mac --mac-source 48:5D:60:FC:29:B0 -j RETURN
COMMIT

[root@localhost:~ ] $ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.2.0.1                 ether   48:5D:60:FC:29:B0   C                     br0

i would like to delete the iptable rule (-D internet -m mac --mac-source 48:5D:60:FC:29:B0 -j RETURN) if the mac on ARP list is not present.

Comment: is there any approach in iptables to delete the line it self if there is not packet passing through? that consider as an IDLE

Comment: (update your question, unluckily comment are missing the format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what language would you like that script to be? Any? Because with a shell script that's tedious to say the least...

You could otherwise save the result of your arp + grep and iptables -L in 2 different files, then load those two files in an array. Then it becomes pretty easy, you go through one of the array and if it exist / does not exist in the other, then delete.

```
arp |grep br0 | perl -nle '/her   ([^ ]+)/ && print $1' >file1.txt
iptables -t mangle -L -v -n |grep MAC | perl -nle '/MAC ([^ ]+)/ && print $1' >file2.txt
php do-delete.php
```

And the do-delete.php could be loading the files and run a system() call to delete the entries:

```
<?php
$f1 = file("file1.txt");
$f2 = file("file2.txt");
$to_delete = array_diff($f2, $f1);
foreach($to_delete as $mac)
{
  system('iptables -t mangle -D internet -m mac --mac-source ' . $mac . ' -j RETURN');
}
```

Something like that... (NOTE TESTED!) Notice how the [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) call is easy! Nothing of the sort that I know of in a shell script.

You could also print out the resulting table back in a file.

```
file_put_contents('file3.txt', join($to_delete, "\n") . "\n");
```

Then use that to do the delete from the shell...

Also you could use PHP to generate the first two files using [popen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php).

Comment: Thanks Alexis... the idea of using array_diff() is good.. i will try this function... how about is bash script...

Comment: Thank guys it works now... i basically during the login save the mac in database and start the cron to check each time to see if still exist in arp table if not the delete the iptables rule with the user mac

Comment: What I call the shell is bash or sh. There is easy equivalent to the array_diff(). The only way I know of is using grep on each IP and that would be terribly slow.

Comment: Typed too fast I guess, I meant to say "there is NO easy equivalent".